# Rails 3 + carrierwave + nginx = permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, rubygems, carrierwave

I've installed carrierwave gem with rmagick.

I can get it working fine if load thro WEBrick but getting 500 Internal Server Error when trying to use nginx instead.

The nginx error.log says:

```
2011/08/14 10:06:40 [crit] 760#0: *4247 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.0.4/client_body_temp/0000000033" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jewellery.dev, request: "POST /items/28?locale=en HTTP/1.1", host: "jewellery.dev:8080", referrer: "http://jewellery.dev:8080/items/28/edit?locale=en"
```

Also I've created an file on initializers folder containing:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0777
end
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not related to CarrierWave, Nginx is not being able to write at the folder **/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.0.4/client_body_temp/** with the temporary uploaded file, which means your Nginx process doesn't have rights on it. Make sure the user that's running nginx can read/write files under this specific path, if you have not changed the configuration, Nginx usually starts it's workers as user **nobody** so you might give him read/write acces to this folder.

Run the following command:

```
ps aux | grep "nginx: worker process"
```

And see which user is running nginx.

Comment: That's right. Thank you Maurício! You saved me twice counting on this!  Just did `chown <myuser>:<group> /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.0.4/client_body_temp/`and it works! :)

Comment: In newer versions of nginx, the folder may be **/var/lib/nginx/body**