# File upload not working with Rails 4 in development using Pow and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rack-pow

I am using Pow and Nginx to serve my Rails 4 app in development. A simple file upload is returning 500 error and the request is not reaching the Rails controller. I assume this is the case because there is no mention of the request in the Rails log. Without any mention of the error, I am not sure what is going wrong here.

I started with an Ajax file upload but replaced it with a simple form which is also not working.

Tried this

[image: Original Upload Button]

and then went to this

[image: Simple Upload Form]

**Current avatar.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true }, method: "post", url: '/settings/avatar/update', class: "", id: "update_avatar" do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'js-upload-photo-button js-change-avatar-btn', accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg' %>
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

**Request headers in Chrome**

[image: Full Request Headers]

**Expanded Request Headers section**

[image: Expanded Request Headers section]

**nginx.log**

`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2014:11:28:26 +0530] "POST /settings/avatar/update HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "https://allotrop.dev/settings/avatar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"`

**pow access.log**

`[Sat Feb 01 2014 11:28:26 GMT+0530 (IST)] INFO [127.0.0.1] GET allotrop.dev /500.html`

There are other questions here about Rails returning 500 error with no mention in log [rails 500 error no production log entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564739/rails-500-error-no-production-log-entry)
, [Rails 3.2.13, 500 error in development with no log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891402/rails-3-2-13-500-error-in-development-with-no-log)
and [How to properly diagnose a 500 error (Rails, Passenger, Nginx, Postgres)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970028/how-to-properly-diagnose-a-500-error-rails-passenger-nginx-postgres)

But these are one-off errors and do not seem related to the problem I am facing. It would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction.

**Update 1**

**Relevant line from routes.rb**

`post '/settings/avatar/update', to: 'settings#update_avatar'`

**Update 2**

Found my nginx error log. BTW, if you are using Homebrew, it is at `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.0/logs/error.log`

**nginx/error.log**

`2014/02/01 13:05:54 [crit] 8787#0: *85813 open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000010" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: *.dev, request: "POST /settings/avatar/update HTTP/1.1", host: "allotrop.dev", referrer: "https://allotrop.dev/settings/avatar"`

Comment: Can you check with method: 'PATCH' in your form? If it doesn't will be good if you can update your routes file here.

Comment: Using `Patch` is not helping. I have added the relevant route in the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is not with Rails but with Nginx which is pretty evident from the `nginx error.log`. This question helped me understand what I was dealing with - [Rails 3 + carrierwave + nginx = permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054338/rails-3-carrierwave-nginx-permission-denied).

Nginx uses the [`client_body_temp_path` directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_body_temp_path) to specify the location where it will temporarily store the uploaded files from the user request. Homebrew had set it by default to `/usr/local/var/run/nginx`. This folder also contains `fastcgi_temp`, `proxy_temp`, `scgi_temp` and `uwsgi_temp` for me. Nginx worker processes run with user `nobody` and they were not able to access these folders. I chowned all these folders to the `nobody` user, but that did not help.

Finally, I did

`client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/;` inside the HTTP module of my `nginx.conf` to make it work.

Doing a `ls -l` shows

`drwx------  2 nobody       wheel   68 Feb  1 14:44 nginx`

I am not sure why this worked inside `/tmp` and not inside the original `/var/run/nginx`. I belive I will face similar issue when I use other temp folders or in production. Will update this thread if and when that happens.

I recommend symlinking the other relevant logs like the nginx access and error log, pow access and app log to the `/log` directory of your Rails app. It helps in looking up errors in one of these when you face a tricky bug.

Comment: Thank you @movingahead, adding client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/; solved my issue as well :-)

Comment: Adding client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/; worked for me too!! this should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: Setting `client_body_temp_path` to anything under `/tmp` turned out to be unreliable because OS X would sometimes clean out these directories.  I went back to investigate why the original defaults set up during install (under `/usr/local/var/run/nginx`) weren't working and found that nginx needs execute permissions to be set on all ancestor directories (source: http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/).  In my case, `chmod o+x /usr/local/var` fixed the issue without needing to change `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Had completely same issue, even chmodding the /usr/local/var/run/nginx folders did not resolve permission issue, but `client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/;` did anwer. Thanks!

Comment: Totally saved me here! Thanks!!